# Know where the value of a variable was changed Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know by "watch" the line of code where it was changed the value of a variable. I do not know if this is possible
I want this:

```
$scope.$watch('name', function('magicParameter') {
    console.log('magicParameter');
    });
```

and magicParameter return "file client.js line 124 char 24"
for example..
is posible??
thanks

Comment: You cannot do this in AngularJS

Comment: The best you can do is capture the old value and the new value and try to backtrack where it changed. 

scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log("OldValue: " + oldValue + " NewValue: " + newValue);
});

Comment: @Sharondio that's not a good way to solve the problem :(

Comment: @Federico There is no magic. What Sharondio pointed out is definitely a  solution.

Comment: That isn't solution for me, I need know from where the variable was modify, is for security question

Comment: You cannot do this with Angular.js. You cannot do this with JavaScript. For debugging purposes you could throw an error to see the  stack trace.

Comment: You can use object instead of plain variable, e.g. 
{ variable: 'somedata', whereChanged: <ref to obj> }